# Angular 10 and PrimeNG13

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm working with angular 10,and i want to use the last version of PrimeNG (Version 13),
But i'm not sure if it is compatible or not

Could you please help me ?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2):

PrimeNG majors versions are compatible with the same major versions of Angular from version 7.

So PrimeNG 13 is NOT compatible with Angular 10

You need to install primeng@10

Comment: But i found that the PrimeNG 10 is an LTS version, can i still use it even if it's a commercial version ?